# sed command to extract text from HTML

Tags: html, text, curl, sed, extract

I am grabbing the source of a page useing curl, and want to extract a text from a specific tag.

the text is between the unique tag:

```
href="http://www.website.com/some/unique/page.php?q=xyz">TEXT</a>
```

What I did was:

```
curl -s "http://www.website.com" | sed 's|PATTERN|\1|'
```

Where PATTERN is one of the many regex patterns I have tried, one of which:

```
href="http://www.website.com/some/unique/page.php?q=xyz">\(.*\)</a>
```

But for some reasons, I couldn't get it to work. I either get the full page source or nothing at all (depending on the pattern I used).

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I probably should have used unique "element" instead, as I was in a hurry. Yes, just TEXT

Comment: So do you want to key on the word 'unique' in the URL?

Comment: the source has more than the text that I provided. I want to extract the "TEXT" from the tag A where href="http://www.website.com/some/unique/page.php?q=xyz" just like in the pattern I provided above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your desired output is just `TEXT`, this will work with the input you gave:

```
sed 's/^.*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/'
```

If the *only* output you want is `TEXT` and you only want that to be output from a URL containing the word `unique` in it's path then use this instead:

```
sed -n '/http:.*\/unique\//s/^.*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/p'
```

Comment: that would be any html tag, right? how about the one element I provided above?

Comment: The key being `-n` to print nothing by default and the modifier `p` to print the line that is substituted.

Comment: @nio Right now it will only output `TEXT` if it's on a line that contains the keywords `http:` followed by `/unique/`. If that is not specific enough then just put whatever pattern you want to limit to between the first pair of unescaped `//` and escape out any `/` in your pattern text. Unfortunately, unlike with the `s` command where you can use whatever delimiter you want, the range field must use `//`

Comment: I had to tweak it a little bit, but I got the idea. Thanks