# Extracting string from html file or curl output

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a html file where some of them are "minified", this means that a whole website can be in just one line.

I want to filter the value of `?idsite=` which contains numbers. So a html contains something like this: `img src="//stats.domains.com/piwik.php?idsite=44`.

So the plain output should be "44".

I tried grep but it echos the whole line and just highlights the value.

Comment: How about using sed?

Comment: Is there more then one occurrence of `?idsite=` and can you provide the `URL` so we can see the full page?

Comment: the string is just one time in the html file. my file is under a .htaccess protection but you can see a snippet of the code on the piwik website: http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/ under 'image tracker code'

Comment: Putting the snippet from the page you reference in a file called `idsite.html` and substituting `44` for for the `[$IDSITE]` in the parameter, this bit of perl will extract the "44":  `perl -nE 'say /.*idsite=(..).*$\"/ if /idsite/ ' idsite.html`

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed command to extract text from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464170/sed-command-to-extract-text-from-html)

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` it could be something like:

```
 echo "Whole bunch of stuff  \                                        
  img src=\"stats.domains.com/piwik.php?idsite=44\" " \
  | perl -nE 'say /.*idsite=(..)\"/ '
```

(assumes that `idsite` is always two characters ! **:-)**.  Your regex will need to be more sophisticated than this most likely).

Putting the snippet [from the page you reference above](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/) in an HTML file (non-minified) and subsituting `44` for the parameter variable, this bit of perl will extract the "44":

```
 perl -nE 'say /.*idsite=(..)/ if /idsite/ ' idsite.html
```

Translating the one liner to a `sed` command line would be similar:

```
echo "Whole bunch of stuff  \                                        
 img src=\"stats.domains.com/piwik.php?idsite=44\" " \
 | sed -En "s/^.*idsite=(..)\"/\1/p"
```

This is [POSIX`sed`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed) from FreeBSD (should work on OSX) the `-E` switch is to add "modern" regexes.

Doing it in `awk` is left as an exercise for another community member :-)

Comment: ok this works perfect if the characters are 2 digits and the html is minified. but i tried this one on a non-minified html, and it doesnt work on this.

Comment: If the HTML is not minified and `idsite=44` is followed by other characters or parameters you could try to simply match 2 characters `(..)`. You could probably filter the lines a bit: `perl -nE 'say /.*idsite=(..)/ if /idsite/ ' index.html` might work. A bit of a quick hack though. I guess if you're going to use perl you might as well use a module to parse the tags .. sorry :-D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl way to extract only the trailing digits of strings like src="//stats.domains.com/piwik.php?idsite=44" and run on a bash command line:

```
echo $src|perl -ne '$_ =~m /(\d+$)/; print $1'
```

Here is a python way to do the same thing:

```
import re
print ', '.join( re.findall(r'\d+$', src))
```

If there will be a lot of src strings to process, it would be best to compile the regex when using Python as follows:

```
import re
p = re.compile('\d+$')
print ', '.join(p.findall(src))
```

The import and the compilation only have to be done once.

Here is a Ruby way to do it:

```
puts src.scan( /\d+$/ ).first
```

In all cases the regexes end with "$" which matches the end of the string. That is why they match and extract only digits (\d+) at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to check whether the `idsite` is in the value of a `src` attribute, then all you need is

```
perl -nE'say $1 if /\bidsite=(\d+)' myfile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat site.html
lorem ipsum idsite='4934' fasdf a
other line

$ sed -n  '/idsite/ { s/.*idsite=\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/; p }' < site.html
4934
```

Let me know in case you need an explanation of what is going on.